# Firefox, reload without cache check

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

It looks like a popular question but it's just the opposite.

When I visit a site in Firefox 15 I have two different behaviours when:

1. Pressing enter in the address bar
2. Pressing F5 or the refresh button

If I look in the network console I can see that F5 does a lot more requests, most of them about cached resources and with a 304-Not Modified answer.

Is there's any shortcut to make a quick refresh? Just like pressing enter on the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

(<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac OS X)

Comment: Definitely a good answer. A one step key or button would be more confortable, but I don't know if it exists. Thanks.

Comment: Alt+D is an easier shortcut to press if you are right-handed, in my opinion.